# How to fetch data from couchDB using couch api?

Tags: angularjs, couchdb

Instead keys and IDs alone, I want to get all the docs via couch api. I have tried with GET "http://localhost:5984/db-name/_all_docs" but it returned

```
{
    "total_rows":4,
    "offset":0,
    "rows":[
        {"id":"11","key":"11","value":{"rev":"1-a0206631250822b37640085c490a1b9f"}},
        {"id":"18","key":"18","value":{"rev":"30-f0798ed72ceb3db86501c69ed4efa39b"}},
        {"id":"3","key":"3","value":{"rev":"15-0dcb22bab2b640b4dc0b19e07c945f39"}},
        {"id":"6","key":"6","value":{"rev":"4-d76008cc44109bd31dd32d26ba03125d"}}
    ]
}
```

From the documentation 
for the below request it will send the data as we expected but it requires set of keys in request.
POST /db/_all_docs HTTP/1.1

{
"keys" : [
"11",
"18"
]
}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `_all_docs` endpoint is actually just a system-level view that uses the `_id` field as the index. Thus, any parameters that you can use for views also apply here.

If you read [the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/bulk-api.html) further, you'll find that adding the parameter `include_docs=true` to your view will include the original documents in the results. The documents will be added as the `doc` field alongside `id`, `value` and `rev`.